# Excel formula returns error until I click in formula window

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel macro that imports some data from a different source, rearranges and does some calculations. One of the calculations is shown below.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MAX('FF-48455IL'!P$9:P$500)=0;"";MAX('FF-48455IL'!P$9:P$500));"")
```

This formula is created by the macro and the calculation is returning an error until I select the cell and click in the formula window, after which the calulation returns the correct answer. The calculation options are set to automatic, and pressing "Calculate Sheet" also does not remove the error until after I have clicked in the appropriate formula window.

Using the "Evaluate Formula" function in excel, I can see that the problem is that `max('FF-48455IL'!P$9:P$500)` is the part that is returning the error (#REF!) until after I have clicked in the formula window. I can copy just this part of the formula to a different cell, and the calculation in the new cell will return the correct result, but not in the original cell.

Can anyone tell me why this formula is not working before manual intervention, and how I can get it to return the correct answer without manual intervention? This is one of several formulas that are then imported to a different sheet, so manual intervention each time is not really an option.

The code from the macro that creates the formula is given below. SR is an integer that is counted through - in this case it is 10; CurT in this case is the string "FF-4-8455IL"; LACol is "P"; nHeader is the integer 8.

```
TmpStr2 = "'" & CurT & "'!" & LACol & "$" & nHeader + 1 & ":" & LACol & "$500"    
.Cells(SR, 5).formula = "=iferror(if(max(" & TmpStr2 & ")=0,"""",max(" & TmpStr2 & ")),"""")"
```

In Column P of the Sheet FF-48455IL, Row9 contains a date & time stamp, and at the moment, the rest of the cells are empty, but will later also be filled with date & time stamps. Manually adding a value to Row10 doesn't fix the error message.

Comment: Might help to share the line of code that writes this formula to the cell?

Comment: Thanks BigBen for the suggestion, I just added the code to my original question